# altering spanx in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap ,i used the `.span3` twice in a page.where in one `.span` i need border radius.but not in another. any easy way to do it.i'm always facing problems in customizing these `.spanx` help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="span3 foo">Span A</span>
<span class="span3">Span B</span>
```

And set the border on foo:

```
foo {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Pretty basic CSS knowledge.

Also: I recommend using the [LESS](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/extend.html) version of bootstrap and recommend you read "[Please stop embedding Bootstrap classes in your HTML!](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html)"

Comment: oops ,this is the first day im using bootstrap!

Comment: Also your first day in CSS? Because this is not Bootstrap-specific but just plain basic CSS.

Comment: He/she is asking `border-radius` not border ;)

Comment: @Morpheus Does it matter? The idea is still the same. But I corrected it for all OCD'ers out there ;-)

Comment: thanks for the answer,i ask is there any additive class for border radius in bootstrap?!?!

Comment: @RobIII No, it doesn't :)

Comment: @SangeethK Again: I recommend using the [LESS version](http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html) and use mixins like `border-radius()`. Also [the article](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html) I mentioned in my answer is an important read.